Is processing data on the SQL Server side better or processing on the code side EF? especially for large datasets?
When I use DistinctBy() the memory consumption of my console app rises to 1.5GB.
When I use GroupBy(), the service took 100MB max. So is keeping it on the SQL Server side more efficient or is processing data at code level more efficient?

EF doesn't process data, it's an ORM. That means it Maps Objects to Relational constructs like tables. What you ask is about LINQ and no, it's not faster than the server

do the processing where it makes most sense! No point in bringing all data back to client if you don't need it

Ideally, what you want to do, is to filter out data on the SQL Server side as much as possible and only get the data you actually need in the application layer. SQL Server is really efficient in working with data using "Set based" approach. I know EF many times like to work with data on row by row based. So if you have a need to work with data on Row by row based, pull data into app layer and work with it their but when pulling data filter out the data on SQL server side. Also there are certain operation that are better done in the app layer like Sorting, SQL is not that great when it comes ..

the service took 100MB max. that suggests you processed the data on the client both times, but produced different results. You can't talk about efficiency when you don't use the database at all.

@M.Ali better done in the app layer like Sorting that's completely wrong. The database has already sorted the data and has indexes that can be used when you want different sorting. Even without indexes, the database has far more powerful CPUs, more and faster RAM and disks than any client. SQL Server will parallelize a query if needed. It's also smart enough to use various techniques to cache and sort the data, something that's just not possible on the client

@PanagiotisKanavos im not going to start a Dev Vs DBA argument here. SQL Server does not perform well for sorting and for large datasets it will spill the sorting operation to a disk anyway. Thus performing sort in app layer will be more efficient. Please read about how SQL server does sort and you will understand where I am coming from

@M.Ali dunno, I was a SQL Server MVP, built 6 data warehouses and right now JOINing a 30M-row table with a 10-M row one. And thinking whether I need to add partitioning at some point not for performance, but to make deletion easier

@PanagiotisKanavos opss sorry, but would you not agree that rather than doing sort operations in SQL Server, doing it in the application layer (given that the app has enough memory to play with) will be more efficient?

@M.Ali I think you don't know how databases work. Or at best, have a very specific, limited scenario in mind that doesn't really involve sorting but something else

@M.Ali before you answer anything else, remember that Stack Overflow uses SQL Server and doesn't sort on the client

Well I like to think, I have a little bit knowledge of how SQL Server does sorting behind the scenes and what happens when a sort operator spills on to a disk and how it impacts the performance of a query. Therefore I think doing sort operation in the app layer, is usually a good thing, you may disagree but you havent given any reason why you are making the case other than throwing around your MVP status. :)

You stated by insinuating that I don't know about SQL Server, to support a pretty wild and unfounded claim. A little bit of knowledge is a dangerous thing though. Yes, I know what spooling means. That's what happens if the data isn't indexed and there's so much data it doesn't fit in the server's far larger RAM. What will the client do with data that doesn't fit in RAM? And why did you not add an index to begin with?

Very true, if you are working with a very large dataset that it will max out the memory of the app but I think you have also overlooked the fact, that the VERY LARGE MEMORY of SQL Server is not available for every query to use it all. There will be a memory grant for each query and if SQL server is having to sort the dataset, if it fits in the allocated "memory grant" it will do the operation in the memory, if it doesnt it will spill the data on to a disk. And as you would agree, as soon as query spills/hits to the disk, the performance of that query will be terrible.

@PanagiotisKanavos here is another MVP who would agree with me Brent Ozar. Please have a read https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/02/7-things-developers-should-know-about-sql-server/

That's not what he says

@PanagiotisKanavos Lets agree to disagree. Maybe we have a different perspective of things. All the best mate.

actually I am just retrieving the data through that query. var objList = _context.table.Where(x=> x.DepartmentId == Id).GroupBy(x=>x.StaffName).ToList()

For larger datasets it is better to process data on the SQL Server side as it will result in better performance and scalability.
